# Laravel - RetaurantLoginController Exist But Error Show Restaurant Login Controller Does Not Exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Restaurant\RestaurantLoginController does not exist error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `RouteServiceProvider.php` inside `Providers` directory and uncomment the line where it is mentioned:

```php
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your codebase, you can try the following:

- Check your class path (including casing): It has to match the namespace and class name case-sensitive